# How to Enclose an Entire Google Sheets .csv Column in Quotes?

Tags: excel, csv, google-sheets

I'm currently trying to enclose an entire column in a Google Sheets CSV file in double quotes for a script that I'm writing. I've attached a link for the sample CSV sheet below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qhXEG_IxBzjTDkq0r2L-9MTAM6iO1L7qDFJCnkcI4n4/edit?usp=sharing

When I export this sheet then the first cell in the 2nd row will be enclosed in quotations due to the special characters, but the second cell will not be as it does not have any special characters. For consistency when reading from a cell I want entries in the second column to be enclosed in double quotes.

I'm hoping for something simple such as changing a setting in the Google Sheets or potentially a function as I'm trying to make my script as dummy proof and simple for non-tech users. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this function before exporting the content of your sheets to enclose the entire 2nd column with double quotes:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1); 
  var values = range.getValues();
  var quoted = values.map(x => x.map(y => '"' + y + '"'));
  
  range.setValues(quoted);
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**UPDATED Ver:**

I added a ternary operator which works if we'll be adding a single if-else like condition for arrow functions in javascript.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow(),1); 
  var values = range.getValues();
  var quoted = values.map(x => x.map(y => y[0] == '"' && y[y.toString.length] == '"' ? y : '"' + y + '"' ));
  range.setValues(quoted);
}
```

Comment: Hi Diego, Where and how would I run this function? Apologies, I'm unfamiliar with google sheets

Comment: @user1721182 on your designated Google Sheets, click on the Extensions tab and you'll see the App Script option, click on it and it should open a new App Script project. Copy and Paste the code above, and save. Then, you can click on the Run option and on the first instance you click on Run, it should prompt you for an authentication since this is a [container-bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) script, that accesses the Sheet Service. Then once authorization is complete, run it again.

Comment: Hi Diego, I have a follow-up question to this. How would I make it so that if the value is already quoted to not add in another set of quotation marks?

Comment: @user1721182 edited my answer above, added a modified version of the original script. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)